# Excel : how to put a literal dot into a cell format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Whenever I put a dot character into a custom cell format Excel will interpret it as if I want a *decimal separator* in that location of the format. The problem being that decimal separator changes with the locale. I actually just want a dot.

Here's an example format that won't work:

`hh:mm:ss.000`

(it won't work because if the locale uses anything else than a dot as a decimal separator then you'll see something like `22:31:34,854` in your formatted value)

I've tried something like

`hh:mm:ss\.000`

to make Excel understand that I really want a dot. However Excel 2010 refuses to accept that as a valid format. (I've read somewhere that the `\` is the way to escape a character in an Excel format string)

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish as end result?

Comment: I hope that was obvious:  I want to format a time value with milliseconds. The problem I have is that Excel will interpret the `.` in the format string as meaning _decimal separator_ rather than simply just printing a dot.

Comment: I am able to use hh:mm:ss.000 format just fine on a cell for time what version of excel are you using?

Comment: It's not about being able to use the `hh:mm:ss.000` format, it's about being sure that the dot is really a dot. I bet you didn't test on a locale where your decimal separator is say a comma ?? If so you would notice that Excel would print your formatted timeval as something like `06:33:55,872` and that is **not** what I want. I just want a dot (literally). As indicated in the question I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-excel/formating-cells-to-time-format-to-include/bdec10eb-1ecf-413b-9344-1b7f626820e6?auth=1

Comment: @Antony. I've looked at the link. I don't know if you meant it as a solution or simply as something to be investigated. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @peterh not an answer but my bad  for not reading question and comments fully, I can see your dilemma as the comma and period are recognised at a global level so even something like using country code =SUBSTITUTE((TEXT(A1,"[$-809]hh:mm:ss,000")),",",".",1)  does not work as the dual format for the system parameter does not get recognised.

Comment: @peterh you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way in Excel to create a time format for display such as

`hh:mm:ss.SSS`

where `hh` is hours (24h), `mm` is minutes, `ss` is seconds and `SSS` is milliseconds and where the separator in front of the milliseconds is always a dot. You can only do it if you accept that the separator in front of the milliseconds will change with the locale. One way to phrase why we get into trouble here, is to say that Excel doesn't really support the concept of milliseconds, it only supports the concept of fractions on seconds. There's a subtle difference.

You can ask Excel to print the seconds-fractions, by suffixing the seconds meta character (typically `ss`) with `<decimal-separator-char>000`, for example a custom number format such as

`hh:mm:ss.000`    (if your current decimal separator character is '.')

or

`hh:mm:ss,000`    (if your current decimal separator character is ',')

If you read the official documentation from Microsoft it doesn't really say that you have to use the decimal separator character used in the current locale, it just says that you should use a `.`. This is simply not true.

The only way to create the requested time format in an invariant way is to create your own String-concatenation-and-formatting formula in the cell. It'll be ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to use the "Text" cell format and use a formula that will output a text value with the required separators

```
=LEFT(A1;2) & ":" & MID(A1;4;2) & ":" & MID(A1;7;2) & "." & RIGHT(A1;3)
```

Excel doesn't handle milliseconds in named formats...

Comment: Sure, I can always do text tricks but that will mean that the _content_ of the cell will no longer be a numeric and hence no longer an Excel time value.